# Why am I not getting the styles from Google font site using Angular2-Material with Webpack

Tags: webpack, angular-material, angular-material2

So I have 2 projects, one works on [gulp](https://github.com/jrgleason/ng2-demo-app/tree/playing-around). Now I am trying to port this over to using webpack in [this project](https://github.com/jrgleason/ng2-webpack-demo).

The problem is I don't seem to be able to include the ngMaterial icon. When I check the styling it looks like it is getting the Angular2 Material styles...

(The left side shows the successful gulp project, whereas the right is the failing Webpack based project)

[image]

Can someone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Dope I was missing...

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```